# AWS Elasticsearch Update version 6.3 -> 7.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am newbie and started to use some AWS services these days. I have a little bit confused about how I update AWS ES version 6x to 7x, what I should concern about it? Any effect on the existed data on ES. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before performing an upgrade Amazon [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-version-migration.html) performing the following steps:

1. Pre-upgrade checks – Amazon ES performs a series of checks for issues that can block an upgrade and doesn't proceed to the next step unless these checks succeed.
2. Snapshot – Amazon ES takes a snapshot of the Elasticsearch cluster and doesn't proceed to the next step unless the snapshot succeeds. If the upgrade fails, Amazon ES uses this snapshot to restore the cluster to its original state. For more information about this snapshot, see Can't Downgrade After Upgrade.
3. Upgrade – Amazon ES starts the upgrade, which can take from 15 minutes to several hours to complete. Kibana might be unavailable during some or all of the upgrade.

If you're using a single node you may experience downtime during this upgrade from between 15 minutes to several hours, however Amazon do perform checks prior to validate that your data will be compatible with the newer version. If you have a multi node setup, upgraded nodes will be rotated to not affect your service.